# How do I rebind AUCTeX C-c ` to display errors?

Tags: errors, compiling, auctex

AUCTeX provides shortcut <kbd>C-c `</kbd> to display compilation errors.
This is particularly annoying on my keyboard.
How can I tell AUCTeX that I want to use say <kbd>C-c +</kbd> instead?

Comment: Quote from [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html):  _Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case) are reserved for users; they are the only sequences reserved for users._

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative

Running `` C-h k C-c ` ``, auctex mentioned that this shortcut runs `TeX-next-error` and that it is bound to `` C-c ` ``, `` C-x ` ``, `M-g n` and  `M-g M-n`. So perhaps some of the other ones are more suited to you.

Knowing what the command behind it, makes it easy to make your own shortcut. There are loads of guides for this online.